# Redeploy/Failover for Glassfish cluster on EC2?

Tags: deployment, glassfish, amazon-ec2, failover

I have a **Tapestry** application (**WAR**, no EJB) that ...

- ... I want to deploy on 2 **EC2** small instances (for **failover**).
- ... uses **Spring Security**
- ... is **stateful** (very small session state)
- ... should be deployed on **Glassfish 3.1** (seems to have best cluster support?)
- ... and has an elastic **load balancer** with **sticky session** in front of it

How can I configure a cluster to achieve minimal ('no') interruptions for the user experience in case A) *a node fails* and B) *I deploy a new version*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/docinfo.html#scrolltoc

Basically, you setup a DAS (=master), which control nodes with instances on it. You could do all of this on the same machine (1 DAS, 1 node with multiple instances), although it would be a good idea to have at least 2.

You should then have at least one load balancer (apache, physical load balancer, whatever).

A) if a node fails, the load balancer can redirect all traffic to the other node

B)

- deploy application, disabled, with new version (see "application versioning")
- mark server A as unavailable
- enable the new version on server A
- mark server A as available and server B as unavailable
- enable the new version on server B
- mark server B as avalilable